# Add attribute to <input> in jQuery each loop ONLY on first pass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage that prints out "inventory" from an SQL table and the option to *remove* inventory by entering the *amount to be removed* in the column the *item* is in.

[image: pic1]

Note: The SQL table has the rows "item" and "amount"(inventory), and I added the amount column to the printed HTML table for the ability to remove items from stock.

I want to be able to label each input tag to have the attribute 'name' be equal to the item name.

ex:

First row - `<input ... name='Apple'>`

Second row - `<input ... name='Banana'>`

I am using jQuery each loop, that prints each column and using attr() to add the attribute but the main issue is that it adds the attribute for each column but it overwrites the name attribute for each column.

ex:

First pass: `<input ... name='Apple'>`

Second pass: `<input ... name='10'>`

**What I've tried:**

I tried fixing this by adding an if-statement to only add the 'name' attribute to input if the input tag doesn't have one, my thought process was that during the first pass, the input tag doesn't have the name attribute so it'll add one, then during the next pass the if condition will be false and it won't modify the input tag.

You'll see from the comments in the code what else I've tried but none of it seems to give me the result I need.

Here is the jQuery code I am using to print the HTML table:

```
function DISPLAY_INVENTORY(JSON_DATA) {
    var COL_NAMES = ['Item', 'Inventory', 'Amount'];

    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON_DATA);
    var $TABLE_OBJ = $('<table class="table table-striped" >');
    $TABLE_OBJ.attr('id', 'student_table');
    $list.append($TABLE_OBJ);

    // $(output).append($TABLE_OBJ);

    //Print a table header
    var $ROW_OBJ = $('<tr>');
    var $THEAD = $('<thead class="thead-light">');
    $THEAD.append($ROW_OBJ);
    $TABLE_OBJ.append($THEAD);

    for (var j = 0; j < COL_NAMES.length; j++) {
      var $TB_HEADER = $('<th>');
      $TB_HEADER.html(COL_NAMES[j]);
      $ROW_OBJ.append($TB_HEADER);
    }

    $TBODY = $('<tbody>');

    //Print rows
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (i == data.length - 1) {
        $TABLE_OBJ.append($TBODY);
      }

      $ROW_OBJ = $('<tr>');
      $TBODY.append($ROW_OBJ);

      //Print columns
      $.each(data[i], function(key, value) {
        // if (i % 2 == 0) {
        //   var ITEM_NAME = value;
        // }

        $COL_OBJ = $('<td>');
        $INP_OBJ = $('<input class="text-center form-control" type="text" size="3">');
        if (!$INP_OBJ.attr('name')) {
          $INP_OBJ.attr('name', value);

          // $INP_OBJ.attr('id', ITEM_NAME);
        }

        // $INP_OBJ.attr('name', ITEM_NAME);
        // $INP_OBJ.attr('id', ITEM_NAME);
        $COL_OBJ.html(value);
        $ROW_OBJ.append($COL_OBJ);
      });

      $ROW_OBJ.append($INP_OBJ);
    }
  }
```

The JSON data:

```
[{"item":"Apple","amount":"10"},
{"item":"Banana","amount":"11"},
{"item":"Corn","amount":"12"},
{"item":"Deli Sandwich","amount":"5"},
{"item":"Egg Plant","amount":"12"},
{"item":"French Fries","amount":"15"},
{"item":"Green Beans","amount":"21"},
{"item":"Hamburgers","amount":"7"},
{"item":"Ice Cream","amount":"3"},
{"item":"Jell-O","amount":"12"},
{"item":"Kiwi","amount":"8"},
{"item":"Lima Beans","amount":"32"},
{"item":"Mashed Potatoes","amount":"11"},
{"item":"Noodle Soup","amount":"54"},
{"item":"Orange","amount":"10"},
{"item":"Pear","amount":"5"},
{"item":"Quinoa","amount":"4"},
{"item":"Raisins","amount":"12"},
{"item":"String Cheese","amount":"16"},
{"item":"Tomato Soup","amount":"23"},
{"item":"Unsalted Nuts","amount":"19"},
{"item":"Vienna Sausage","amount":"24"},
{"item":"Wheat Bread","amount":"15"},
{"item":"Xavier Soup","amount":"17"},
{"item":"Yogurt","amount":"11"},
{"item":"Zucchini","amount":"12"}]
```

If anyone could help me out or point me in the right direction with the logic that would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: What does your JSON data look like?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). You're **creating** the `input` in your nested loop (the `$.each` loop nested within the `for` loop), but the picture you've shown only had a single `input` in it. I don't see how the code shown can produce the picture you've shown.

Comment: @ConstantinGroß Added edit with JSON data being encoded by PHP from SQL table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this with the least adaption of your code necessary would be to use a variable, let's call it `rowItemName`and update its value only when the `key` in the `$.each()` loop equals "item". Then you can use the variable when setting the input name:

```js
$list = $('#list');

function DISPLAY_INVENTORY(JSON_DATA) {
  var COL_NAMES = ['Item', 'Inventory', 'Amount'];

  var data = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON_DATA);
  var $TABLE_OBJ = $('<table class="table table-striped" >');
  $TABLE_OBJ.attr('id', 'student_table');
  $list.append($TABLE_OBJ);

  // $(output).append($TABLE_OBJ);

  //Print a table header
  var $ROW_OBJ = $('<tr>');
  var $THEAD = $('<thead class="thead-light">');
  $THEAD.append($ROW_OBJ);
  $TABLE_OBJ.append($THEAD);

  for (var j = 0; j < COL_NAMES.length; j++) {
    var $TB_HEADER = $('<th>');
    $TB_HEADER.html(COL_NAMES[j]);
    $ROW_OBJ.append($TB_HEADER);
  }

  $TBODY = $('<tbody>');

  //Print rows
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (i == data.length - 1) {
      $TABLE_OBJ.append($TBODY);
    }

    $ROW_OBJ = $('<tr>');
    $TBODY.append($ROW_OBJ);
    
    

    //Print columns
    var rowItemName;
    $.each(data[i], function(key, value) {
      if (key === 'item') {
        rowItemName = value;
      }
      // if (i % 2 == 0) {
      //   var ITEM_NAME = value;
      // }

      $COL_OBJ = $('<td>');
      $INP_OBJ = $('<input class="text-center form-control" type="text" size="3">');
      if (!$INP_OBJ.attr('name')) {
        $INP_OBJ.attr('name', rowItemName);

        // $INP_OBJ.attr('id', ITEM_NAME);
      }

      // $INP_OBJ.attr('name', ITEM_NAME);
      // $INP_OBJ.attr('id', ITEM_NAME);
      $COL_OBJ.html(value);
      $ROW_OBJ.append($COL_OBJ);
    });

    $ROW_OBJ.append($INP_OBJ);
  }
}

// using JSON.stringify() here only for demonstration
// so I can pass JSON as a string as the function expects
DISPLAY_INVENTORY(JSON.stringify([{"item":"Apple","amount":"10"},
{"item":"Banana","amount":"11"},
{"item":"Corn","amount":"12"},
{"item":"Deli Sandwich","amount":"5"},
{"item":"Egg Plant","amount":"12"},
{"item":"French Fries","amount":"15"},
{"item":"Green Beans","amount":"21"},
{"item":"Hamburgers","amount":"7"},
{"item":"Ice Cream","amount":"3"},
{"item":"Jell-O","amount":"12"},
{"item":"Kiwi","amount":"8"},
{"item":"Lima Beans","amount":"32"},
{"item":"Mashed Potatoes","amount":"11"},
{"item":"Noodle Soup","amount":"54"},
{"item":"Orange","amount":"10"},
{"item":"Pear","amount":"5"},
{"item":"Quinoa","amount":"4"},
{"item":"Raisins","amount":"12"},
{"item":"String Cheese","amount":"16"},
{"item":"Tomato Soup","amount":"23"},
{"item":"Unsalted Nuts","amount":"19"},
{"item":"Vienna Sausage","amount":"24"},
{"item":"Wheat Bread","amount":"15"},
{"item":"Xavier Soup","amount":"17"},
{"item":"Yogurt","amount":"11"},
{"item":"Zucchini","amount":"12"}]
))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list"></div>
```

However, you can reduce and simplify your code greatly while even increasing performance (adding each HTML element via jQuery is more costly than building the markup as a string and then adding it to the DOM in one go):

```js
$list = $('#list');

function DISPLAY_INVENTORY(JSON_DATA) {
  var COL_NAMES = ['Item', 'Inventory', 'Amount'];

  var data = $.parseJSON(JSON_DATA);
  var TABLE_MARKUP = '<table class="table table-striped" id="student_table">';
  TABLE_MARKUP += '<tr><th>' + COL_NAMES.join('</th><th>') + '</th><tbody>';
  
  
  $.each(data, function(key, row) {
    TABLE_MARKUP += '<tr><td>' + row.item + '</td><td>' + row.amount + '</td><td><input class="text-center form-control" type="text" size="3" name="' + row.item + '"></td></tr>';
  });
  
  TABLE_MARKUP += '</tbody>';
  $list.html(TABLE_MARKUP);
}

// using JSON.stringify() here only for demonstration
// so I can pass JSON as a string as the function expects
DISPLAY_INVENTORY(JSON.stringify([{"item":"Apple","amount":"10"},
{"item":"Banana","amount":"11"},
{"item":"Corn","amount":"12"},
{"item":"Deli Sandwich","amount":"5"},
{"item":"Egg Plant","amount":"12"},
{"item":"French Fries","amount":"15"},
{"item":"Green Beans","amount":"21"},
{"item":"Hamburgers","amount":"7"},
{"item":"Ice Cream","amount":"3"},
{"item":"Jell-O","amount":"12"},
{"item":"Kiwi","amount":"8"},
{"item":"Lima Beans","amount":"32"},
{"item":"Mashed Potatoes","amount":"11"},
{"item":"Noodle Soup","amount":"54"},
{"item":"Orange","amount":"10"},
{"item":"Pear","amount":"5"},
{"item":"Quinoa","amount":"4"},
{"item":"Raisins","amount":"12"},
{"item":"String Cheese","amount":"16"},
{"item":"Tomato Soup","amount":"23"},
{"item":"Unsalted Nuts","amount":"19"},
{"item":"Vienna Sausage","amount":"24"},
{"item":"Wheat Bread","amount":"15"},
{"item":"Xavier Soup","amount":"17"},
{"item":"Yogurt","amount":"11"},
{"item":"Zucchini","amount":"12"}]
))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list"></div>
```

It could even be simplified further using template literals, `JSON.parse()` and native `forEach()`, depending on the legacy browser support needed. Voilà, no jQuery needed:

```js
function DISPLAY_INVENTORY(JSON_DATA) {
  var COL_NAMES = ['Item', 'Inventory', 'Amount'];

  var data = JSON.parse(JSON_DATA);
  var TABLE_MARKUP = `<table class="table table-striped" id="student_table">
    <tr><th>${COL_NAMES.join('</th><th>')}</th><tbody>`;
  
  data.forEach((row) => {
    TABLE_MARKUP += `<tr><td>${row.item}</td><td>${row.amount}</td><td><input class="text-center form-control" type="text" size="3" name="${row.item}"></td></tr>`;
  });
  
  TABLE_MARKUP += '</tbody>';
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = TABLE_MARKUP;
}

// using JSON.stringify() here only for demonstration
// so I can pass JSON as a string as the function expects
DISPLAY_INVENTORY(JSON.stringify([{"item":"Apple","amount":"10"},
{"item":"Banana","amount":"11"},
{"item":"Corn","amount":"12"},
{"item":"Deli Sandwich","amount":"5"},
{"item":"Egg Plant","amount":"12"},
{"item":"French Fries","amount":"15"},
{"item":"Green Beans","amount":"21"},
{"item":"Hamburgers","amount":"7"},
{"item":"Ice Cream","amount":"3"},
{"item":"Jell-O","amount":"12"},
{"item":"Kiwi","amount":"8"},
{"item":"Lima Beans","amount":"32"},
{"item":"Mashed Potatoes","amount":"11"},
{"item":"Noodle Soup","amount":"54"},
{"item":"Orange","amount":"10"},
{"item":"Pear","amount":"5"},
{"item":"Quinoa","amount":"4"},
{"item":"Raisins","amount":"12"},
{"item":"String Cheese","amount":"16"},
{"item":"Tomato Soup","amount":"23"},
{"item":"Unsalted Nuts","amount":"19"},
{"item":"Vienna Sausage","amount":"24"},
{"item":"Wheat Bread","amount":"15"},
{"item":"Xavier Soup","amount":"17"},
{"item":"Yogurt","amount":"11"},
{"item":"Zucchini","amount":"12"}]
))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: That's a great solution! I was kind of on track to that with my ITEM_NAME var but I can see where that didn't work. Thanks for the help, I'd love to see how my code can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

One common way to handle data attributes on elements is to prepend `data-` to the attribute. This way you can attach multiple attributes to an element without them being overwritten. For example, you could write:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  $INP_OBJ = $('<input class="text-center form-control" type="text" size="3">');
  $INP_OBJ.attr('data-item', value.item);
  $INP_OBJ.attr('data-amount', value.amount);
}
```

And then you can reference them later using:

```
// get amount
var amount = $INP_OBJ.attr('data-amount');
```